# Kivy app just load then closed in android

Tags: android, kivy

I've built my app on windows using bash and buildozer, it's successfully done, then I've put the apk on my android 7 phone, but it's just loading then closed without any message or anything. How can I solve this?

Comment: How we can help you without any clue?Please read [mcve] and [ask] and provide us a better description of your problem please.

Comment: Try running `buildozer android deploy run logcat` with your phone connected to your PC. Then have a look at the logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

> Put some break points and debug the code to check where what is going on!

Comment: i did so but in vain

Comment: your given information is not enough to dig in @ashrafkhaled

Answer (score 0):

this is my code  , i dont know why cant i run the api

```
import kivy
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from ipify import get_ip
import geocoder
from datetime import datetime





class MainPage(GridLayout):
    # runs on initialization
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        #used for grid
        self.cols = 1



        #Labels
        self.IP_label = TextInput(text = " IP Address " , height = Window.size[0]*0.16)
        self.Mac_address = TextInput(text = "MAC Address" , height = Window.size[0]*0.16)
        self.GPS = TextInput(text = "GPS(Lat,Lon)" , height= Window.size[0]*0.16)
        self.time_stamp = TextInput(text = "Time" , height = Window.size[0]*0.16)

        #buttons
        self.get_ip = Button(text = " Get IP "  , height = Window.size[0]*0.16  , on_press = self.get_public_ip)
        self.get_loc = Button(text = "get_Loc" , height = Window.size[0] , on_press = self.get_location_mac_time)


        #adding widgets
        self.add_widget(self.IP_label)
        self.add_widget(self.Mac_address)
        self.add_widget(self.GPS)
        self.add_widget(self.time_stamp)
        self.add_widget(self.get_ip)
        self.add_widget(self.get_loc)


    #functions
    def get_public_ip(self,instance):
        ip = get('https://ip.seeip.org').text
        self.IP_label.text = 'My public IP address is: {}'.format(ip)
        with open('Public_IP.txt', 'w') as k:
            print('My public IP address is: {}'.format(ip) , file = k)

    def get_location_mac_time(self,instance):
        g = geocoder.ip('me')
        Time_now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        k= tuple(g.latlng)
        my_dict = {}
        for idx, val in enumerate(k): 
            my_dict["v{}".format(idx)] = str(val)

        self.Mac_address.text = "The MAC address is : "+':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode()))
        self.GPS.text = my_dict['v0'] + ',' +  my_dict['v1']
        self.time_stamp.text = "timestamp :"+ Time_now
        with open('loc_mac_time.txt', 'w') as f:
            print(Time_now, "    ",my_dict['v0'],"    ",my_dict['v1'],"    " ,':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode())),file=f)

class test_app(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainPage()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_app().run()



and no error to show i swear , i cant build the api i dont know why
```